# Where can I find the full list of Google/Microsoft CDN hosted AJAX files?

Tags: google, ajax, cdn, microsoft

While Google hosts [this list](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/) and Microsoft hosts [this one](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx) there are several files missing such as [jQuery UI CSS](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css). Where can I find a complete listing of all the resources offered for major AJAX CDNs, especially Google and Microsoft (due to popularity)?

**CDNs listings found so far** (mostly thanks to [artlung](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/26/artlung)):

- Google:
  http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation
  *([Darryl Hein](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/210/darryl-hein) also found http://scriptsrc.net for easier access)*
- Microsoft: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx
- AOL: http://o.aolcdn.com (can only find http://dev.aol.com/dojo for references to URLs)
- Yahoo: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/articles/hosting

**Google CDN Hosted jQuery UI Themes**

[Base](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css), [Black-Tie](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css), [Blitzer](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css), [Cupertino](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css), [Dark-Hive](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css), [Dot-Luv](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/dot-luv/jquery-ui.css), [Eggplant](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/eggplant/jquery-ui.css), [Excite-Bike](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/excite-bike/jquery-ui.css), [Flick](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css), [Hot-Sneaks](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/hot-sneaks/jquery-ui.css), [Humanity](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/humanity/jquery-ui.css), [Le-Frog](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/le-frog/jquery-ui.css), [Mint-Choc](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/mint-choc/jquery-ui.css), [Overcast](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/overcast/jquery-ui.css), [Pepper-Grinder](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui.css), [Redmond](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css), [Smoothness](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css), [South-Street](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/south-street/jquery-ui.css), [Start](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/start/jquery-ui.css), [Sunny](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css), [Swanky-Purse](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/swanky-purse/jquery-ui.css), [Trontastic](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/trontastic/jquery-ui.css), [UI-Darkness](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css), [UI-Lightness](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css) and [Vader](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/vader/jquery-ui.css).

**EDIT:**

Just use [CDN JS](http://www.cdnjs.com/) for all the hosting from one domain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Specifically for jQuery UI there's a MAINFEST file at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/MANIFEST which includes paths relative to that file for the jQuery UI files. The CSS file in your example actually does exist. I'm seeing CSS at:

> http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

Maybe I'm misunderstanding you though?

The Microsoft CDN is cool, but totally new to me.

Here's an interesting article on [pros and cons of using JavaScript CDN](http://zoompf.com/blog/2010/01/should-you-use-javascript-library-cdns).

Comment: No I think you are understanding me perfectly - the manifest is pure gold. Also thank you for the article link. I'll leave the question hanging for a couple of days to see if someone has a more thoroughly collated site though.

Comment: Yeah, I like the question. I suspect that people will have to crawl the CDNs to get a full manifest. I suspect it will also change. You might update the question with other CDNs you want info for. I ran into this wondering if the AOL CDN for dojo had everything from dojo.

Comment: Good idea *rolls up sleeves*

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a true list for both Google and Microsoft, but it lists the ones Google hosts: http://scriptsrc.net/ and provides nice JS for copying the needed HTML.

Google also hosts the CSS and associated images for jQuery UI at `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css` where blitzer is the theme name.