# Does Google host all the jQuery UI themes?

Tags: google, css, jquery

I have seen the base theme http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.3/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

Are the other themes found in the gallery also hosted (Darkness, Smoothness, etc.)?  If so, where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the [manifest](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/MANIFEST) - I believe they're all there.

Answer (score 1):

The complete list of theme CSS files to include is on [Where can I find the full list of Google/Microsoft CDN hosted AJAX files?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1256/where-can-i-find-the-full-list-of-google-microsoft-cdn-hosted-ajax-files)